# Prevent open -a Terminal.app from automatically exiting on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, script

On my Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks, I wrote a small bash script to open a log file for a terminal game application I'm writing so I can see print statements:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\e[3;0;0t'                                  # move
printf '\e[8;35;61'                                 # resize
tail -f ~/Library/Logs/Aaron/logfile--[default].txt # open log file
```

And I open it from another script like this (which contains other various 
calls to setup my dev environment not shown here):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\e[3;681;0t'                     # move
printf '\e[8;35;61t'                     # resize
open -a Terminal.app scripts/view_log.sh # open log file in new window
printf '\e[5t'                           # request focus
```

It all works great except that when I cancel execution of tail, it auto exits the terminal.  I notice at the top of the terminal it has the following prompt:

```
/Users/aaron/code/c/game2/scripts/view_log.sh ; exit;
```

How can I prevent the terminal from prepending this exit command?  Is there a way to launch a new Terminal and keep it around to use for other commands afterwards?

*(Someone [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal) suggested adding the line `$SHELL` at the end of the script, but that was for Ubuntu's gnome-terminal)*

Answer (score 0):

One [simplistic way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040214/2429404) is spawning a new shell at the end of your script. Just put the command

```
bash
```

as the last line in your `view_log.sh` script.

It's not pretty, as you normally don't want to open another subshell, but it keeps the original window open.